# Random Band Name Generator

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to make a random band name generator in vb.net but whenever i randomly generate it shows a number rather than a word from my combo boxes

```vb
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub btnMake_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnMake.Click

        Randomize()

        ComboBox1.Text = Int(Rnd() * ComboBox1.Items.Count)

        ComboBox2.Text = Int(Rnd() * ComboBox2.Items.Count)

        txtResult.Text = ComboBox1.Text + " " + ComboBox2.Text

    End Sub

    Private Sub btnFavourite_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnFavourite.Click
        ListBox1.Items.Add(txtResult.Text)
    End Sub

End Class
```

it should print one of the names that I've put into the combo box at random but it gives me random numbers instead

Comment: You need to get a particular item from a ComboBox using the generated random number, like `Dim part1 As String = ComboBox1.Items(CInt(Rnd() * (ComboBox1.Items.Count - 1))).ToString()`.

Answer (score 1):

Set the [SelectedIndex property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.combobox.selectedindex?view=netframework-4.8) instead of Text

```
ComboBox1.SelectedIndex = Int(Rnd() * ComboBox1.Items.Count)
```

Answer (score 1):

Put `Option Strict On` at the top of your code file. You will see the compile error

> Option Strict On disallows implicit conversions from 'Single' to 'String'.

on this line

```
ComboBox1.Text = Int(Rnd() * ComboBox1.Items.Count)
```

because [Int()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/int-fix-functions) returns the integer portion of a number *in the same type it was passed*. So pass it a single, and it returns a single.

From Microsoft.VisualBasic metadata:

```vb
' Summary:
'     Return the integer portion of a number.
' ...
Public Function Int(Number As Single) As Single
```

But you don't want to set the ComboBox.Text equal to a number anyway. You may want to set the ComboBox.SelectedIndex. You can try

```
ComboBox1.SelectedIndex = Int(Rnd() * ComboBox1.Items.Count)
```

but with `Option Strict On`, you still have type mismatch because you're trying to set an integer to a single. You could wrap `Int` in a `CInt` conversion

```
ComboBox1.SelectedIndex = CInt(Int(Rnd() * ComboBox1.Items.Count))
```

but now it's getting out of hand...

Here's the issue: you're using outdated functions, `Int` and `Rnd`. These were brought over from VB6 days and if you use VB.NET functions, it's a whole lot easier. See the [Random](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.random?view=netframework-4.8) class. Using Random, you have access to Random.Next, which actually returns an integer. Great!

```vb
Dim r As New Random()
ComboBox1.SelectedIndex = r.Next(ComboBox1.Items.Count)
ComboBox2.SelectedIndex = r.Next(ComboBox2.Items.Count)
```

Here is the complete code (with an added event handler to update txtResult whenever the indices are changed i.e. when the user manually changes one)

```vb
Private Sub btnMake_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnMake.Click
    Dim r As New Random()
    ComboBox1.SelectedIndex = r.Next(ComboBox1.Items.Count)
    ComboBox2.SelectedIndex = r.Next(ComboBox2.Items.Count)
End Sub

Private Sub ComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged, ComboBox2.SelectedIndexChanged
    txtResult.Text = ComboBox1.Text & " " & ComboBox2.Text
End Sub

Private Sub btnFavourite_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnFavourite.Click
    ListBox1.Items.Add(txtResult.Text)
End Sub
```